# Inheritence and Lists in JPA-RS: items don't show up at expected parent element

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, moxy, jpa-rs

Given a root class with a property `private List<Base> items` and `Base` being an `abstract` class:

```
// omitted properties, Constructor, Getter, Setter, etc.

@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ROOT_TO_BASE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ROOT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "BASE_ID") })
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ITEMS")
    @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "FOO", type = Foo.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "BAR", type = Bar.class) })
    private List<Base> items;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@XmlSeeAlso({ Foo.class, Bar.class })
public class Base implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(name = "BASE-NAME")
    private String baseName;

}
```

The expected output for an entity of Root `<base-url>/persistence/PU/entity/Root/123` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT ID="123">
    <ITEMS>
        <_link href="<base-url>/persistence/PU/entity/Foo/6" method="GET" rel="self" />
        <_link href="<base-url>/persistence/PU/entity/Bar/7" method="GET" rel="self" />
    </ITEMS>
    <_relationships>
        <_link href="<base-url>/persistence/PU/entity/Root/123/items" rel="items"/>
    </_relationships>
</ROOT>
```

But actually it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT ID="123">
    <ITEMS/>
    <_relationships>
        <_link href="<base-url>/persistence/PU/entity/Root/123/items" rel="items"/>
    </_relationships>
</ROOT>
```

The elements are available at the provided url, but to me that's not consistent with the usual JPA-RS model.
Question: Is it a bug or intended for inherited classes?

I'm using EL 2.5.1.v20130918